# TSQL - how to avoid truncating or rounding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For some reason, the data in the `ORIGINAL_BOOK` column (even though it has 2 decimals (eg. 876.76)), the statement below truncates the decimals. I want the decimals to be visible as well. Can someone suggest how to fix this issue please?

```
Case 
   When [DN].[SETTLEMENT_DATE] > [DN].[AS_OF_DATE] 
      Then Cast([DN].[ORIGINAL_BOOK] as decimal(28, 2))
      Else Cast([DN].[CURRENT_BOOK] as decimal(28, 2))
End
```

Comment: What is the data type of `CURRENT_BOOK`? How are the values stored there? Look at culture specific differences such as dot or comma to separate the decimals if this is a string value...

Comment: In what way are the decimal places _invisible_? As written the `CASE` expression will always return a value with two decimal places (or NULL). What do you do with that value?

Comment: Both fields ORIGINAL_BOOK  and CURRENT_BOOK Numeric

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure because you only say that the type of the fields involved is `NUMERIC`, without specifying any precision or scale, however if your source fields really are just `NUMERIC` type, SQL defaults to `NUMERIC(18,0)` (as per MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187746.aspx)) and so you will only be able to store values with a scale of zero (i.e. no value after the decimal place) and any values written to these fields with a greater scale (i.e. data after the decimal place) will be rounded accordingly:

```
CREATE TABLE dn (
    ORIGINAL_BOOK NUMERIC,
    CURRENT_BOOK NUMERIC
)

INSERT INTO dn
SELECT 876.76, 423.75
UNION
SELECT 0, 0
UNION
SELECT 1.1, 6.5
UNION
SELECT 12, 54
UNION
SELECT 5.789, 6.321

SELECT  CAST(dn.ORIGINAL_BOOK AS DECIMAL(28,2)) AS ORIGINAL_BOOK_CONV,
        CAST(dn.CURRENT_BOOK AS DECIMAL(28,2)) AS CURRENT_BOOK_CONV
FROM dn

DROP TABLE dn
```

gives results:

```
/----------------------------------------\
| ORIGINAL_BOOK_CONV | CURRENT_BOOK_CONV |
|--------------------+-------------------|
| 0.00               | 0.00              |
| 1.00               | 7.00              |
| 6.00               | 6.00              |
| 12.00              | 54.00             |
| 877.00             | 424.00            |
\----------------------------------------/
```

Increasing the scale of the field in the table will allow values with greater numbers of decimal places to be stored and your `CAST` call will then reduce the number of decimal places if appropriate:

```
CREATE TABLE dn (
    ORIGINAL_BOOK NUMERIC(28,3),
    CURRENT_BOOK NUMERIC(28,3)
)

INSERT INTO dn
SELECT 876.76, 423.75
UNION
SELECT 0, 0
UNION
SELECT 1.1, 6.5
UNION
SELECT 12, 54
UNION
SELECT 5.789, 6.321

SELECT  CAST(dn.ORIGINAL_BOOK AS DECIMAL(28,2)) AS ORIGINAL_BOOK_CONV,
        CAST(dn.CURRENT_BOOK AS DECIMAL(28,2)) AS CURRENT_BOOK_CONV
FROM dn

DROP TABLE dn
```

gives results:

```
/----------------------------------------\
| ORIGINAL_BOOK_CONV | CURRENT_BOOK_CONV |
|--------------------+-------------------|
| 0.00               | 0.00              |
| 1.10               | 6.50              |
| 5.79               | 6.32              |
| 12.00              | 54.00             |
| 876.76             | 423.75            |
\----------------------------------------/
```

If you are sure that your table fields are capable of containing numeric values to more than zero decimal places (i.e. scale > 0), please post the CREATE TABLE script for the table (you can get this from SSMS) or a screenshot of the Column listing so we can see the true type of the underlying fields. It would also be useful to see values `SELECT`ed from the fields without any `CAST`ing so we can see how the data is presented without any conversion.